# PyQtGraph live plot multiple lines of data

Tags: python, arduino, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to plot multiple lines of data from an arduino in PyQtGraph. I want that the code itself recognize how many lines of data it has to plot but currently I don't see any data in PyQtGraph.
Here is my code what I've tried so far.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys 
import os
import serial
import numpy as np


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.graphWidget.plotItem.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.5)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART', 9600) 
        self.x1 = np.array([])
        self.y1 = np.array([])
        self.xp = np.array([])
        self.yp = np.array([])
        self.dateien = 0 
        self.count = 0

        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.get_Data)
        self.timer.start()

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=20)
        self.data_line =  self.graphWidget.plot(self.xp, self.yp, pen=pen)

    def plot(self, xp, yp):
        self.data_line.setData(xp, yp)

    def get_Data(self): 
        self.data = self.ser.readline()
        try:
            self.count = self.count + 1
            self.x1 = np.append(self.x1, self.count)
            self.decoded_data = str(self.data[0:len(self.data)-2].decode("utf-8"))
            self.dataArray = self.decoded_data.split()
            array_length = len(self.dataArray)
            for i in range(array_length): 
                 self.dateien = self.dataArray[i]
                 self.y1 = np.append(self.y1, float(self.dateien))
                 print(self.x1.shape, self.y1.shape)
                 self.data_line.setData(self.x1, self.y1)
        except (UnicodeDecodeError): 
             print("Error")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The "UnicodeDecodeError" appears at the first reading of the serial data.
My current output look like this:

```
Exception: X and Y arrays must be the same shape--got (122,) and (121,).
```

At the end it should look something like the arduino plotter. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi, could you supply the data so that we can see its format and help with what is going on?  There is a good guide for asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: oh of course. I edited the program a bit and removed the error message "IndexError".

Comment: Could you supply the exact line where the problem or the error is raising?

Comment: I guess the problem is when `get_Data` is called for the last time because you add another value to the `x1` variable, and maybe the last value of `y`  is a `None` value, so i will not append anything in the `y1` variable. If my guess is right,  then you will have a difference in one value, the solution will be testing the `y` value, and if it isn't `None` you append the new value to the `x1` variable.